# How can I update existing config from a custom module's config/install yamls?

Tags: 8, installation, configuration

I added some config yml files to my module's config/install directory so that it is installed directly when installing my module, it works well only if there isn't a config file with the same name installed already and only if it's the first install.
  So my question is there a way to update the config files already installed with my module's config file, and delete them when uninstalling the module ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend reinventing the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module. But let's say this is a contrib module and you updated the install yamls that won't fire on sites that had that module installed already, you need to additionally provide your entity changes via [`hook_update_N`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.2.x) programmatically.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more details and context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A module install should not update config. If you want to update existing config, your module should implement `hook_update_N()` ([see docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/introduction-to-update-api-for-drupal-8)) instead.

However, you could add a `dependencies: enforced` section to your YML config files. This will remove your existing config on module uninstall, and install the newest config on module reinstall. This way you can "emulate" a simple update mechanism for your own, private custom module. See [doc for enforced config dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/node/2404447)

Answer (score 1):

You can update custom config with a settings form you build. 
In a custom module *custom_mailing* add a file called *custom_mailing.routing.yml* add the following route:

```
custom_mailing.route_admin_settings:
  path: '/admin/config/mailing'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Custom mailing'
    _form: '\Drupal\custom_mailing\Form\AdminSettingsForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer custom_mailing settings'
```

Now I want a boolean value to be editable. I create a file in a map `config/install` called *custom_mailings.settings.yml* with the following content:

```
mailsettings:
  enabled: 0
```

In a module called *custom_mailing*. Inside `src/Form` add file called `AdminSettingsForm.php`.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_mailing\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class AdminSettingsForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\custom_mailing\Form
 */
class AdminSettingsForm extends ConfigFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'custom_mailing_admin_settings_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      'custom_mailing.settings',
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('custom_mailing.settings');

    $form['mailsettings'] = [
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Email settings'),
    ];

    $form['mailsettings']['enabled'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => $this->t('Enable sending of e-mails.'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('mailsettings.enabled'),
    ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('custom_mailing.settings');
    $config->set('mailsettings', $form_state->getValue('mailsettings'));
    $config->save();
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
  }

}
```

Comment: Config will be deleted when disabling the module btw